# it means imagined rather than actual

Tags: modal-verbs

1. In the way I was using the word "hypothetical" here, it means imagined rather than actual, regardless of how likely or unlikely something is deemed to be. *In general usage, the degree of likelihood **may** be implied by context.*

Can I paraphrase the "may" like this:

*In general usage, **it is possible** for the degree of likelihood to be implied by context*.

Can I replace the "may" with "can"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether your audience is readers or writers. For an audience of writers you are telling them that they are able to imply the degree of likelihood using context. *Can* says it is possible; *may* says it is their choice. There is little practical difference.

For an audience of readers either *can* or *may* says that the author might have used the context to carry the information. *May* is more often used; *can* says that it is possible to do it. In this case it is the context which "may imply" the degree of likelihood. You might consider using *the context* instead of *context* if this is the intended meaning.

If you are referring to the reader's actions and choices you need the word *infer* instead of *imply*. Writers and the text imply, readers infer.

Comment: It seems you took "readers" or "writers" as the "agent" of the verb "imply". What if the agent is the word "context"? For example: *In general usage, context **may** imply the degree of likelihood*. Is this interpretation possible? If so, can I replace the "may" with "can"?

Comment: I've edited my response to answer this. I like the suggestion in your comment, because it is in active voice. Using active voice instead of passive voice makes it much easier to be clear about exactly what you mean.